# Debouncing and Setting text data not happening at the same time

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the debounce feature as well as the ability to retain the value of textbox that I typed but it's not happening for some reason. If I comment out `setMyval(e.target.value);` on line #20 then the debounce works without any issue but the value I type does not show up. Whereas if I uncomment it, then the value shows in the textbox but debounce feature does not work (meaning there are multiple console logs). Please if someone can tell me why is this happening and how can I make it work, it would help me.

Below is my reactjs code:

```
// App.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import debounce from "./debounce";


function App() {
  const [myval, setMyval] = useState("");

  const handleChange = debounce(() => {
    console.log("This log msg should be debounced");
  }, 2000);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={myval}
        onChange={e => {
          setMyval(e.target.value);
          handleChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setMyval("my new value")}>Change Value</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```
// debounce.js
export default function debounce(fn, wait) {
  let timer;
  return function() {
    const context = this;
    const args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

Code at https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-wind-0ef3y

What I expect:

1. If I type a word in the textbox, the value should remain in the textbox.
2. Debounce should work i.e. few console logs should appear.
3. If I click on the "Change Value" button, it should update the value "my new value" in the textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-turing-w4hu9

Your debounce doesnt work, because your debounce function gets redeclared on every component update. Use useCallback to keep the reference the same and avoid reinitialization

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import debounce from "./debounce";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [myval, setMyval] = useState("");

  const handleChange = useCallback(debounce(() => {
    console.log("This log msg should be debounced");
  }, 2000), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={myval}
        onChange={e => {
          setMyval(e.target.value);
          handleChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setMyval("my new value")}>Change Value</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. This code works like a charm. So to get a more clear picture, what if the "useCallback" function wasn't available in React. Was there a custom way of doing this? Or how do we build our own useCallback function?

Comment: @Phantom007 I don't understand what you are asking. Your problem was that variable `handleChange` was constantly reinitializing on every component render. The solution was to make sure that variable is only initialized `once`. A custom way of doing that is to move that function outside of component scope to not get affected by rerenders?